# clearTimeout during gallery animation

Tags: jquery, animation, settimeout, setinterval

I created a gallery with auto-play.

When the gallery STOP it's animation and we hover the gallery, all works as expected.

But I am getting a strange issue:

**While the gallery is animating** --> hovering the gallery, the **clearTimeout seem not to work correctly** and on mouseleave the gallery behave strangely
 or it's happening a strange conflict I cannot understand and resolve. I went back to an other gallery I made a couple of days before fith a similar functionality and I encountered the same issue.

I am missing something crucial here

**THE GALLERY IN QUESTION: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/PXVSW/)**

```
var myTimeOut;

/////// ANIMATION /////////////   
    function animation(cb){         
            $('#slider').animate({left: '-=600' },800, cb);
    }      
    /////// AUTO SLIDE ////////////
    function auto() {
        myTimeOut = setTimeout(function() {
            animation(function(){
                auto();                   
            });   
        }, 2000);
    }
    auto();
```

and how I'm trying to pause it:

```
    ///// MOUSE actions //////////   
    $('#galcontainer').mouseenter( function () {
      clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
    });
    $('#galcontainer').mouseleave( function () {
     auto();
    });
```

### EDIT

Adding a 'hover flag' (as suggested in the answers) works almost great, but a small bug using this solution is visible when 'fast mouseenter/mouseleave DURING the animation.

A fix to that issue could be adding a $('#slider').stop() at mouseleave. Not a great solution. 
What else can I do?

Comment: Javascript does not support multitasking, and since animating is actually a loop, I don't think you can stop it that way. There are native jQuery possibilities I think though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The issue***: on `mouseenter` during the animation, the jQuery `.animate()` callback `cb` is already in queue (even if the clearTimeout was called, another `auto()` will be called which will trigger subsequent runs, etc.).

Using `setInterval` and leveraging all those callbacks is the key:

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PXVSW/21/)***

```js
$(function(){                 // DOM ready shorthand
    var $sli =  $("#slider"), // Cache elements you plan to reuse
        galW =  $('#gallery').width(),
        imgN =  $sli.find('img').length,
        counter = 0,          // set it to index 0!
        itv;                  // setInterval (scope var)
    
    $sli.width(galW * imgN);

    function anim() {
      ++counter; counter%=imgN;                       // Incr.counter; and wrap-around
      $sli.stop().animate({left: -galW*counter},900); // width*counter = px position
    }
    function autoSlide() {
        itv = setInterval(anim, 3000);
    }
    autoSlide();
    
    ///// MOUSE STATE //////////   
    $sli.hover(function(){ clearInterval(itv); }, autoSlide);
});
```

```css
#galcontainer{
    position:relative;
    margin:20px auto;
    width:600px;
}
#gallery{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:600px;
    height:240px;
}
#slider{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#slider img{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="galcontainer">    
    <div id="gallery">    
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x240/479/fff"/>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x240/636/fff"/>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x240/587/fff"/>
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x240/447/fff"/>
        </div>     
    </div>   
</div>
```

(Aside notes regarding the original (yet modified) code)

The `direction` variable with `"+="` and `"0-"` is unneeded since there's only one direction, so use a `counter = 0` indexed, and wrap-around/reset using the Reminder `%` operator. Also,

```
        animation(function(){
            auto();                   
        });
```

can be written like:

```
       animation(auto);
```

since `auto` is already a function.

```
///// MOUSE STATE //////////   
$('#galcontainer').mouseenter( function () {
  clearInterval(myTimeOut);
});
$('#galcontainer').mouseleave( function () {
 auto();
});
```

can be used with `.hover(fn1, fn2)` method (like in the above example)

Answer (score 3):

When the animation is in progress sometimes the mouseout event is not getting triggered so `pause` variable is not set to false. when next mouseoever event is triggered since pause is not `false` it will again set the timeout. I just made sure we clear any previous timeout before setting the new one.

Take a look at this working demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Lzxs/3/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that during the animation, there is no timeout to stop.  The one timeout has already fired and other is not created until the animation completes.  Because of this, if you hover when the animation is in progress, the animation continues.  You can solve this with a flag to tell whether or not the animation should be stopped.  If the flag is set, auto returns and does not set another timeout.

http://jsfiddle.net/PXVSW/6/

Comment: Basically that flag indicates whether or not the animation should be stopped.  So when it tries to run `auto` it will check if it should run or not. If it should not run, it will `return` which basically just exits the method.  So it will exit without setting a new timeout.

Comment: Hi... I found a bug in your example. If (fast) mouseenter AND mouseleave DURING the animation... crazy things happen. Please, do you have any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work if your mouse enters while the animation is running.  That's because the timer has already fired and the end of the animation is going to start a new one when it completes.  The least rewrite I can think of to solve this would be to set a global flag when you're hovered that the auto function checks so it won't start a new animation if that global flag is set.

You can see the `hoverFlag` solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EaKnj/.

An interesting case to test is to make your mouse enter when the animation is running.

Comment: +1 Actually as I described the problem IS! when the mouse enters while animation is running. The demo works great!

Comment: Hi... I found a bug in your example. If (fast) mouseenter AND mouseleave DURING the animation... crazy things happen. Please, do you have any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: There are apparently some circumstances where the browser won't reliably give you mouseenter/mouseleave events.  You can fix the issue with the changes shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EaKnj/.

Comment: Thanks very many! :) nice solution indeed! (working too) It was the timeout that due to animations buildups tryed to recuperate it's state. (I think ;) ) Clearing the timeout before calling it clears all the remaining issues and now the gallery become a real beauty! Thanks! http://roxon.in/scripts/tutorials/NavGallery_jQuery_Tutorial_01/index5.html

Answer (score 1):

Without digging too deeply into your code, I fixed it by adding a couple of extra checks.

First, I made it so there's no worry about the timeOut identifier getting replaced. I use an array in case multiple events get stacked on top of each other, and clear all of the timeouts in that array.

Second, I added a stop() value and made it so the animation won't run if stopped is true.

Here's the fiddle with my changes: http://jsfiddle.net/6WhNw/

Comment: +1 (the extra checks are over complicating a bit the simplicity of the gallery... but I like them! :D )

Comment: Yeah, it was the lazy way to fix it. I often see a variable being set to the result of a setTimeout() call, and the event calling setTimeout() fired more than once before clearTimeout() gets called. Storing up the setTimeout() results in an array is a simple way to fix it.

Comment: It seems it wasn't necessary in this case, though.

Comment: Hi Ben... in your DEMO you use `myTimeouts` , `myTimeOut` and `myTimeOuts` ... I think I'm lost a bit. What's the right one... In any case this does not work as we expected. Do you have any idea how to fix my issues? (I commented other answers too)

Comment: I meant for them all to be the same. I only saw one difference though. I fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6WhNw/1/

Comment: I don't know if it fixes the issues you were having with it, but it might.

Answer (score 1):

I found that scrolling (which is, well, a sort of animation too) on iOS 6 seems to cause the same problem: timeouts are not cleared reliably as long as a view scrolls.

I considered this an iOS Bug and - in my case - found a solution not using set and clearTimeout.

The same issue couldn't be reproduced in (several) Android Stock Browsers and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using setInterval instead of setTimeout.  Since the animation was calling the callback, it would call the animation over and over.

http://jsfiddle.net/PXVSW/7/

```
var galW =  $('#gallery').width() ,
    imgN =  $('#slider img').length ,
    direction,      // direction ( -=  or  0- ) // set initially to 'null','undefined'
    counter = 1,    // counter
    myTimeOut;       // global setTimeout

$('#slider').width(galW * imgN);

/////// ANIMATION /////////////   
function animation(){                 // cb : makes animation accept a callback
        $('#slider').animate({left: direction+''+galW},800);
}  

/////// AUTO SLIDE ////////////
function auto() {
    myTimeOut = setInterval(function() {
        if ( counter != imgN){           // if counter != '4' (N of Images)
            counter++                    // add '1' to counter
            direction = '-=';            // set direction to go 'left' 
        }
        else{
            counter = 1;
            direction = '0-';            // trick - to bring slider to '0px' left (start position)
        }
        animation();   
    }, 2000);
}
auto();

///// MOUSE STATE //////////   
$('#galcontainer').mouseenter( function () {
  clearInterval(myTimeOut);
});
$('#galcontainer').mouseleave( function () {
 auto();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am afraid this will not work. setInterval creates event buildups when page is off focus or when you return to it from another tab. Than the gallery tries to compensate all animations at once.